# Token transfer with splToken throwing error wehen asking to sign

Tags: javascript, web3js, solana, solana-web3js

Made a function to transfer a custom token on Solana with spl-token, but when i get to sign the transaction it prompts me this error:

`Error processing intruction 2: invalid accounr data for instrction`

Code:

```
transferToken = async () => {
    const tokenAddress = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey("5jFnsfx36DyGk8uVGrbXnVUMTsBkPXGpx6e69BiGFzko");
    const receiver = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(settings.reciver);

    const blockhash = await this.connection.getRecentBlockhash();

    const from = await splToken.Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        splToken.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        tokenAddress,
        this.publicKey
    );

    const to = await splToken.Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        splToken.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        tokenAddress,
        receiver
    );

    let instructions = splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction(
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        from,
        to,
        this.publicKey,
        [],
        1000000000
    );

    let transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction();
    transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash.blockhash; 

    transaction.add(instructions);

    transaction.feePayer = this.publicKey; 

    const signedTransaction = await this.provider.signTransaction(transaction);
    let signature = await this.connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction);
    await this.connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
    console.log(signature);
}
```

I don't understand why this is not working right..

I tried looking up some similar problems, but nothing really helps

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide the library you are using, but I guess it is `@solana/spl-token`.
If so, you are not passing the correct parameters for `getAssociatedTokenAddress`.

Please have a look at the documentation: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/functions/getAssociatedTokenAddress.html.

It should be:

```
    const from = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        tokenAddress,
        this.publicKey
    );
    const to = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        tokenAddress,
        receiver
    );
```